# LibGDX render sprites in tiled-map format ( convert texture to sprite )

Tags: textures, sprites, libgdx, rendering

I am creating a game in which till now I have used textures to create A 2D tiled game.
I have created a matrix which converts the touch co-ordinates into a array index number and according to that index number, a specific tile gets selected. The problem is that I want to emulate the same behaviour for sprites instead of textures. But I get stuck on what could possibly be given as the co-ordinates for the sprite position? I want to just use Sprites instead of using textures as Sprites are easier to animate. No matter which values I give, the screen remains white and sometimes a different tile's texture gets rendered at a different position. What am I doing wrong?

```
//      Function returns the position of tile touched   
int getPos(int screenX, int screenY) {
    x = screenX / (int)xSize;
    y = screenY / (int)ySize;
    y = Squares_Y - 1 - y;
    int result = y * Squares_X + x;
    return result;
}

// Previous Render function
public void render(float delta) {
    batch.begin();
    Tile current=initial_layout;
    if(current.topLink != null)
    {
        for (int Pos=0; Pos<Squares_X; Pos++) {
            for (int ypos=0; ypos<Squares_Y; ypos++) {
                batch.draw(bg_texture, Pos * xSize, ypos * ySize, xSize, ySize);
                if(current!= null)
                {
                    batch.draw(current.getTexture(), Pos * xSize, ypos * ySize, xSize, ySize);
                    current=current.topLink;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){
        if(win == false)
        {
            int x =Gdx.input.getX();
            int y =Gdx.input.getY();
            touchDown(getPos(x, y));
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("\nLevel Completed !! : " + utils.level);
            game.dispose();
        }
    }
    batch.end();
}

// New Render Function
public void render() {
    batch.begin();
    Tile current=initial_layout;
    if(current.topLink != null)
    {
        for (int Pos=0; Pos<Squares_X; Pos++) {
            for (int ypos=0; ypos<Squares_Y; ypos++) {
                batch.draw(bg_texture, Pos * xSize, ypos * ySize, xSize, ySize);
                if(current!= null)
                {
                    spriteBatch.begin();
                    texture = current.getTexture();
                    sprite = new Sprite(texture,(int)xSize,(int)ySize);
                    sprite.setPosition(Pos * xSize, ypos * ySize);
//                  batch.draw(current.getTexture(), Pos * xSize, ypos * ySize, xSize, ySize);
                    sprite.draw(spriteBatch);
                    current=current.topLink;
                    spriteBatch.end();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){
        if(win == false)
        {
            int x =Gdx.input.getX();
            int y =Gdx.input.getY();
            touchDown(getPos(x, y));
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("\nGame WON for Level : "+utils.level);
            game.dispose();
        }
    }
    batch.end();
}
```

Comment: Why are you using two spritebatch? In your first example you used one spritebatch, it was a good approach, why would use a second one when using sprites?

Comment: 'batch' is a normal Batch instance for rendering other textures and 'spriteBatch' is my SpriteBatch instance. There are not 2 spritebatches.